# Colorbox Resize with Multiple Instances in a Responsive Site

Tags: jquery, colorbox, resize, media-queries

I am trying to use colorbox with an upcoming responsive site.  I don't have any issues setting the initial widths upon load.  You can see that here.

```
links4.live( 'click', function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).tipsy("hide");

    $.colorbox({
        href: this.href,
        width: function() {
            if( $('.content').width() < windowWidth3) {
                eventWidth = view4+'px'
            } else if( ($('.content').width() >= windowWidth3) && ($('.content').width() < windowWidth2) ) {
                eventWidth = view3+'px'

            } else if( ($('.content').width() >= windowWidth2) && ($('.content').width() < windowWidth1)  ) {
                eventWidth = view2+'px'
            } else {
                eventWidth = view1+'px'
            }

            return eventWidth;
        },
        initialWidth: '100px',
        initialHeight: '100px',
        scrolling: false
    });
});
```

I am running into an issue with the colorbox resize function and the window resize function.  I am using colorbox on two types of content, which have different settings like width.  When I set a window resize function for colorbox I need to set different resize widths for each content type.

Window Width - 960px
Content 1 - 885px
Content 2 - 767px

Window Width - 768px
Content 1 - 644px
Content 2 - 300px

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    // #1
    $.colorbox.resize({
        width: 644+'px'
    });

    // #2
    $.colorbox.resize({
        width: 300+'px'
    });
});
```

When I try to resize the content types colorbox will resize both content types to one single width.  How can I apply the resize function to specific instances of colorbox so I can set different widths?

Comment: you may be interested in [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185286/two-different-colorbox-popups-on-same-page-separate-settings) where you can have 2 completely different colorbox instances and so resize them separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a time you only show a single colorbox on the screen so in the `window` resize event just set the width of the current colorbox which is visible.

Try this.

```
var currentColorBox = 
links4.live( 'click', function(e) {     
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).tipsy("hide");

    //This will be used in the window.resize event handler
    currentColorBox = this.href;

    $.colorbox({
        href: this.href,
        width: function() {
            ....
            ...
        },
        initialWidth: '100px',
        initialHeight: '100px',
        scrolling: false
    });
});

$(window).resize( function() {
    if(currentColorBox == "specifyCorrectTheUrl"){
         $.colorbox.resize({
             width: 644+'px'
         });
    }
    else{
         $.colorbox.resize({
             width: 300+'px'
         });
});
```

Comment: ShankarSangoli - Thanks for the suggestion.  I am using the CMS ExpressionEngine so the urls are dynamic.  But you did point me down the right path, thx.  I am checking for specific classes in the colorbox instead of urls.