# Colorbox behaving inconsistently when called on an external HTML file

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I am having a weird problem while using colorbox to call "div" element from an other HTML file. The code totally works, except for the last "div" in my external file.
I have something like this in my external file;

div1
  img
  para1
/div1

div2
  img
  para2
/div2

divlast
  img
  paralast
/divlast

My problem is, the colorbox is rendering complete div1 and div2 on call, but when I call "divlast" it is displaying only the "img" element but the "p" element disappears. I tried replacing the order of the divs, and this behavior repeats only with the div at the end, and I just cant figure out what is wrong??

Comment: can you put up a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Okay here you go,this is how my external file would look. And on specifying the different "div" id's I am able to display just one div at a time in my colorbox, except the last div displays only the image but no "p" part
http://jsfiddle.net/z9wuA/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just me but in your code you call for div id #divlast but your last div id is #div3

It may help you to check out my post on [multiple colorboxes on same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185286/two-different-colorbox-popups-on-same-page-separate-settings)

Comment: Oh thats just something I used to explain.. In my code, the last "div" is displayed, but as I mentioned above, its incomplete.. meaning: in every "div", I have an "img" element and "p" element, and when I call "lastdiv" only "img" element gets displayed and this happenes only to the "div" placed at the end of the file...

Comment: In your fiddle the last p is displayed fine even though your js calls for the wrong id

Comment: The fiddle doesnt help as it is. Make it function. Add the colobox js and css. You need to reproduce the problem for us to fix it

Comment: Well this is how far I could reproduce the code
http://jsfiddle.net/BV5j2/   and I couldnt really create the problem here. The weird thing is the code was working just fine this morning and with a small update on the width of the colorbox, though the rest of the page works fine, the last div is inconsistent.

Comment: that's no better. how about a link to the live site?